Can't import mail and contacts from Yahoo Mail
I'm trying to import my contacts from Yahoo! to Gmail so I can close my Yahoo! account.
When I navigate to the Accounts and import tab in Gmail settings, the Import mail and contacts link does not allow me to click on it.  Why?

Is this a personal Gmail account or a work or school account?
